# Decision Tree Classifier with Sparse Matrix

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I noticed on [Google Summer of Code 2013](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/wiki/A-list-of-topics-for-a-Google-Summer-of-Code-%28GSOC%29-2013) that a possible project was implement sparse matrix support for Decision Trees and ensemble methods. Out of curiosity, did this project get anywhere? I really need to incorporate sparse features into a Decision Tree (and from there, a Random Forest) to finish up some research.

If sparse matrix support for Decision Trees has not been added, is there any work-around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a list of possible topics. There was no GSOC project on this one, as you can see from the fact that no student is assigned.

The obvious usually intractable work-around is making the data dense. I am not aware of any better. With the recent refactorings, it might be not as hard to implement this now, so maybe you should give it a try.